# How to allocate memory for a tuple array in Julia?

Tags: arrays, tuples, julia

Is it possible to allocate memory for a `Tuple{String,Any}` type in Julia like

```
s = 100
tup_array = Tuple{String,Any}[s]
```

If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

You can do (on Julia 0.4):

```
s = 100
tup_array = Array(Tuple{String,Any}, s)
```